# Does this Catfolk build have any redundancy?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation

So my Barbarian / Kensai Magus was just killed (R.I.P) and I have to make a new 5th level character. I want a character with personality but at the same time be able to kick some ass.

After reading different [Catfolk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-catfolk) builds on the web, I was thinking something along the lines of:

2 levels of [Urban Barbarian](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/archetypes/paizo---barbarian-archetypes/urban-barbarian) with [Beast Totem rage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/beast-totem-lesser-su)
Beast Totem: 2 claw attacks that deal 1d6 points of slashing damage
Urban barbarian: +4 morale bonus to either STR, DEX or CON. Does not loose AC bonus.

3 levels Ranger [Shapeshifter](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/archetypes/paizo---ranger-archetypes/shapeshifter) archtype
Natural weapon combat style: Improved Natural Attack (gives 1d8 claw attack)
Form of the Bear:  +4 enhancement bonus to Strength

From this I read that I can have +8 STR when I'm raging and using Form of the Bear.

FEATS

- [Catfolk Exemplar (Catfolk)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/catfolk-exemplar-catfolk)
- Power Attack (Combat) -2/+4
- [Aspect of the Beast](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/aspect-of-the-beast)

At his point I'm a bit confused. It seems I can do 2 claw attacks at full BAB as they are both primary weapons. But do I only have 1d8 or 1d10 in damage?

There is a long thread [here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?290042-Natural-attack-rules-questions-Pathfinder) which deals with some of my issues. But there is no clear answer.

**Is it redundant to select:**

- Catfolk with Cat's Claws
- Beast Totem
- Catfolk Exemplar
- Aspect of the Beast

That is, are any of those choices "wasted" in the sense that they provide benefits I'm already getting from one of the other choices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cat's Claws and Aspect of the Beast (claws of the beast manifestation) are redundant because they give the same benefit. Having either one will give you 2 1d4 claw attacks, and either one will let Catfolk Exemplar upgrade those claws to 1d6 via Sharp Claws. You don't get any extra benefit from having both (Rules-lawyering you might get away with having 4 claw attacks, one for each hand and foot, but that seems contrary to RAI).

Beast Totem Rage gives you 2 claw attacks for 1d6 each while you are raging.

Unless you want to go the aforementioned rules-lawyering route and attack with your feet, you can't use more than 2 of your claw attacks, it doesn't matter how you get them. So you can either go with Beast Totem Rage, or Cat's Claws and Exemplar, or Aspect of the Beast and Exemplar, the different attacks don't augment each other so the end result is the same.

[Improved Natural Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/improved-natural-attack) will improve any of your attacks (since they are all claw type).

A generous GM might give you some benefit for having so many redundant sources of natural attacks, but house-rules are house-rules.